# trying to check user entered mail already in database or not

Tags: php, html

can anyone help me where exactly I am going wrong with this code? I got wrong when I am trying to check if email already exists in database or not.

how can I check if email exists in DB or not?

```
       <html>
        <h1> Registration Form </h1>
        <body>
        <form method="post" action="">
       <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="first name" required><br><br>
       <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="last name" required><br><br>
       <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="mail" required> <br><br>
       <input type="PASSWORD" name="pass1" placeholder="password" required> <br><br>
       <input type="PASSWORD" name="pass2" placeholder="repeat password" required> <br>   <br>
       <input type="submit" name="submit">
         </form>


         <?php
         if(isset($_POST['submit']))
           {
       $fname = $_POST['fname'];
       $lname = $_POST['lname'];
       $mail =  $_POST['mail'];
       $pass1 =  $_POST['pass1'];
       $pass2 =  $_POST['pass2'];
       if($pass1 !== $pass2)
        {
      echo "password in correct ";
         }
      else
         { 
      $db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","reviewsystem");
      $check = "SELECT * FROM registers WHERE $mail = email";
      if($check == TRUE){
      echo "email already exists";
          }
       else{
      $query = "INSERT INTO registers(fname,lname,email,password)   VALUES('$fname','$lname','$mail','$pass1')";
       mysqli_query($db,$query);
         echo "  you are registered succesfully";
            }
           }
          }
         ?>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first: you didn't perform any kind of query. You just created a string. Add a line:

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","reviewsystem");
$check = "SELECT * FROM registers WHERE $mail = email";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $check); //i think there is a typo, mysqi_query
```

After that you can use [mysqli_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) which returns number of SELECT rows that came back from DB to identify if the entry already exists:

```
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
     echo "email already exists";
 }
```

Comment: @KrishnaKamal Yeah, just noticed error in query as well. Change it to `"SELECT * FROM registers WHERE email = '$mail' "`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your where clause of mysql query . You must write it as

```
$check = "SELECT * FROM registers WHERE email = '".$mail."'"; if($check == TRUE){ echo "email already exists"; } else{
```